# Is there any programs for Ubuntu that will track a certain face that I want to track

Tags: octave

I tried open_tld but it won't work; I have tried to compile it through  octave manually after following the instructions; but I want to have a list of software for ubuntu that will track certain faces through video and picture that is also open source.

Comment: Any face detection and tracking program written in Octave or Matlab will give same output independent of operating system. What problems are you facing while compiling open_tld?

Comment: "Disclaimer: This project is now old and will no longer be updated. Please have a look at our new tracker CMT instead.". Seems like Georg Nebehay is not updating this project any more.

Comment: good i see and i know what to do

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing this open-source [facerec](http://www.bytefish.de/blog/fisherfaces) software, the detailed documentation including a few examples are also given on their GitHub [page](https://github.com/bytefish/facerec).

This project implements face recognition algorithm for MATLAB/GNU Octave and Python.

Comment: tried to compile it; it didn't work

Comment: Which implementation are you using, py or m?